# Showing error after deploying a Django app

Tags: python, django, heroku

I need help with Heroku. After I have deployed the application, It says application has crashed. This is new to me and I can't spot it on the log file

```
2019-05-02T16:27:20.431826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-02T16:27:26.819416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn basecodetech.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-05-02T16:27:29.189527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-02T16:27:29.199192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-02T16:27:28.956745+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2019-05-02T16:27:28.957547+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:12998 (4)
2019-05-02T16:27:28.957699+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-05-02T16:27:28.964747+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972116+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972119+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972133+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972135+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972137+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972138+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972140+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972142+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972150+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972152+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972153+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972156+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972158+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972159+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972161+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basecodetech'
2019-05-02T16:27:28.972351+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-05-02T16:27:28.996037+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:28 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002135+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002138+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002140+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002141+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002143+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002145+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002146+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002148+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002150+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002151+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002153+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002156+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002158+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002159+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002161+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basecodetech'
2019-05-02T16:27:29.002282+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:29 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-05-02T16:27:29.107321+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-05-02T16:27:29.107435+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-05-02T16:27:29.171553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-05-02T16:27:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-05-02T16:27:36.455360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn basecodetech.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-05-02T16:27:38.569765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-05-02T16:27:38.595111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-02T16:27:38.352182+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2019-05-02T16:27:38.352864+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:25421 (4)
2019-05-02T16:27:38.353000+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-05-02T16:27:38.358968+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364571+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364575+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364597+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364598+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364600+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364602+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364603+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364607+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364610+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364614+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364617+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364619+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basecodetech'
2019-05-02T16:27:38.364716+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-05-02T16:27:38.392761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-05-02T16:27:38.392823+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-02 16:27:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-05-02T16:28:16.617722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=basecodetech.herokuapp.com request_id=a656d580-4a91-4540-ad0c-9a97ed8ab54b fwd="209.88.21.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-02T16:28:17.542998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=basecodetech.herokuapp.com request_id=56ca2181-cb4b-44af-8818-c3a048e9a6d6 fwd="209.88.21.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basecodetech'"

2019-05-02T16:27:28.972161+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basecodetech'

you have to add basecodetech module to requirements.txt

Comment: No, when i add that it says No matching distribution found for basecodetech, which by the the way is the name of the app on heroku

Comment: the error was here `gunicorn basecodetech.wsgi --log-file -`, the apps name is basecode. i just mistaken this with the heroku name.